# Как скрыть код чтобы не отображался на странице

Tags: clipboard.js

Имеется код кнопки копирующий url страницы на которой располагается, но код так хитро написан, что его часть отображается в рамках на странице рядом с кнопкой. 
`<pre><code id="rawgit">&lt;script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/v1.6.1/dist/clipboard.min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</code></pre>
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-clipboard-target="#rawgit">КОПИРОВАТЬ</button>` 
Помогите скрыть, чтобы осталась одна кнопка.

Comment: На какой странице располагается код, и что именно вы видите в clipboard после нажатия на кнопку `Копировать`? Судя по примерам автора clipboard.js, здесь копируется содержимое элемента с `id="rawgit"`, ничего более. Можете назначить элементу `<pre>` стиль `style="display:none"`

Comment: В том поле что мне нужно убрать отображается просто часть кода, то есть код вроде исполняется и в то же время отображается. А код располагаю в обычном php виджете wordpressa. А можно по подробнее про "назначить"? куда именно к кому пристроить style="display:none"

Comment: `<pre style="display:none">`